# Laravel Livewire application without POST forms

Tags: laravel, architecture, laravel-livewire

I'm building a new Laravel 8 application and given the reactivity features available with Livewire package, that essentially turn a backend developer into a full-stack developer (no advanced Javascript knowledge needed), I don't use any POST actions or request handling logic in my scripts. Every CRUD operation is handled with modal windows and AJAX requests. So my question is: Are there some drawbacks in this approach? Are there some limitation that will emerge in the future from the fact that my scripts don't directly handle HTTP request?

Thanks for your opinions.

Answer (score 1):

FYI I'm not familiar with Laravel or Livewire.  I'll use the term "platform" below as a general word to encapsulate technologies and libraries, etc, such as what you describe.

1. Platforms tend to focus on the high-value scenarios that most people need - so as long as what you need the platform to do aligns with what it can do, you're fine (e.g. simple CRUD).  But, if you need to do something that pushes the boundaries of what the platform can do then you'll run into issues: it may not be possible; it's possible but really inefficient / a pig to work on; distorts your architecture and decision making.
2. Platforms like this are good in that they hide complexity, which is great until you need to access it and look under the hood.  This applies to everything from debugging to developing features using approaches that the platform / platform designers haven't allowed for.
3. As a new developer, learning how to do things "the long way" (e.g. hand-code AJAX calls) is great as a learning experience.  By doing that you can better appreciate how platforms like the ones you mention work - because you understand the underlying principles.  So, a disadvantage is that new developers won't get that experience through working on this solution - they'll have to do that as a side project (which is not "evil", but it is a consideration).